# image's center part fit into screen

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, width

Actually, I'm having very big width image. Width is `3000px` and height is `100px`. I need to display *image's center part* in my browser.

If I put my image, It's showing left part of the image. But first I should display center part. If Display screen is big, then side can display.

and it's **inline image** only.

```
<div class="my_img">
  <img src="img.png" >
</div>
```

What can I do?

Comment: Is this an inline image or a background image?

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin:0 auto; display:block;`. This will make it to the center.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/33qZu/  - @KarSho Are you looking for something similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

`contain` scales the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area.

Try:

```
img{background-size:contain;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the center of the image, what you have to do is using a  div instead of an  img. 
In that div's style you set tthe background to be the image you want to show, and then, you center it with css **background-position: 50% 0px**

```
  <div class="my_img">
       <div 
          style="background-image:url(img.png); 
                 height:YOUR_IMAGE_HEIGHT; 
                 background-position: 50% 0px;">
       </div>
</div>
```

with this, if the screen is small, the imagen wiil be cropped and show the center. If the screen is large, youll see the whole image, also centered

Comment: it's i know. I need ans for my question

Comment: with this you will get what you want, no matter what the image widht is (and you dont need to edit the code if you change the image width)

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest way I'm sure, but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/7eA3W/

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/3000x100" alt="" />
</div>


div {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
}
img { 
    margin-left: -1350px; // minus half of the image width, minus half of the container width
}
```

Comment: if i see in big screen means, it's not center.

Comment: The size of your screen shouldn't matter, it's the size of your container element and the negative margin that would affect it.